# How can i convert this my function-based view to class-based view in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

am trying to convert my function based view to class-based view

the problem is that am querying the database twice, the first one is to get all the post in the database from the Post model and the second is to get all the category in the database from the Category model

here is the code

`view.py`:

```
def newPost(request):    
    deyCat = Category.objects.all() 
    if request.method =='POST':
        myForm = NewPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        response_data = {
            'SType': 'danger',
            'message': "An Error Occured, pls try again later"
        }
        if request.POST.get('deyHidden') == 'create_hidden':
            title = request.POST.get('title')
            content = request.POST.get('content')
            category_id = request.POST.get('category')
            image = request.FILES.get('image') 
            if myForm.is_valid():
                if Posts.objects.create(title=title, content=content, category_id=category_id, image=image, author_id=request.user.id):
                    response_data = {
                        'SType': 'success',
                        'message': "Saved Successfully"
                    }   
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")  
        elif request.POST.get('deyHidden') == 'category_hidden':
            CatNames = request.POST.getlist('CatName[]')
            for CatName in CatNames:
                Category.objects.get_or_create(CatName=CatName)
            response_data = {
                'SType': 'success',
                'message': "Saved Successfully"
            }                
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")

    context={
        'form':NewPostForm(),
        'title':'Create Post',
        'category': Category.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/form.html', context)
```

in the `models.py`:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    CatName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.CatName

class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default="1", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='blog_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

pls, how can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render


class NewPostView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'blog/form.html'
    deyCat = Category.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'form': NewPostForm(),
            'title': 'Create Post',
            'category': self.deyCat
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        myForm = NewPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        response_data = {
            'SType': 'danger',
            'message': "An Error Occured, pls try again later"
        }
        if request.POST.get('deyHidden') == 'create_hidden':
            title = request.POST.get('title')
            content = request.POST.get('content')
            category_id = request.POST.get('category')
            image = request.FILES.get('image')
            if myForm.is_valid():
                if Posts.objects.create(title=title, content=content, category_id=category_id, image=image,
                                        author_id=request.user.id):
                    response_data = {
                        'SType': 'success',
                        'message': "Saved Successfully"
                    }
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
        elif request.POST.get('deyHidden') == 'category_hidden':
            CatNames = request.POST.getlist('CatName[]')
            for CatName in CatNames:
                Category.objects.get_or_create(CatName=CatName)
            response_data = {
                'SType': 'success',
                'message': "Saved Successfully"
            }
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: it says invalid syntax  in def(self, request, **kwargs):

Comment: Updated the answer